# Can I use Ktor client websocket with socket.io?

Tags: android, kotlin, websocket, ktor

I have e question.
we have a chat platform that used socket.io in the backend.
Can I use the Ktor client WebSocket library to connect to socket.io or I must use the android socket.io client library?

Comment: You can use Ktor but then you should've implemented the socket.io protocol on top of it. Please see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-448/Socketio-like-WebSockets

Comment: Hi Saeed, could you find a solution for this? I also want to connect to a socket.io using ktor client. Socket.IO version on server is 4+

Comment: @RezaFaraji No, finally I used Socket.IO but I think these links help you :https://github.com/ktorio/ktor-websockets-chat-sample/blob/final/client/src/main/kotlin/com/jetbrains/handson/chat/client/ChatClient.kt                          https://github.com/jamesonwilliams/android-websocket-client/blob/ktor/app/src/main/java/org/nosemaj/wsreader/MainActivity.kt

Comment: @SaeedNoshadi Thank you. If you are working with compose, would you please help me updating my ui with socket update? How did you handle it? I am getting list of updated prices and have to update the price of coins which are visible on the screen avoiding extra recomposition!!

Comment: @RezaFaraji Please create another question about it